# How to use if statements inside foreach loops?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an if statement inside a foreach loop that obtains data from a column named ['online'], the value is either 0 or 1. I'm trying to convert the value to a string like so:

```
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  $datas = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $datas[] = $row;
  }

  foreach($datas as $data){
    $status = $data['online'];
    if($status = 1){
      $status = "Online";
    }else{
      $status = "Offline";
    }
    echo '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
  }
```

If the value is 1 it should be converted to "Online". If it's not 1 then it should be "Offline", currently I get all the results showing as "Online". Not sure why, help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if($status == 1){/*...*/}
```

Istead of

```
if($status = 1){/*...*/}
```

Equal sign is for variable assignment